# Is building an Mobile App (iOS, Android) from a service like Appery.io exportable to continue development with native coding?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to build a Mobile Application (on iOS and Android platforms), but I do not have any programming/coding skills.

Even though, after some Google researches, I found some ways to do that : there are PAAS (Platforms As A Service - like Appery.io, Goodbarber) solutions. Here is a list of them
http://mashable.com/2013/12/03/build-mobile-apps/#8WrrHqnlqqqz

And basically, let's say after a few months of development (not by coding but by a "WYSIWYG" way) on a such service (I'm currently using http://appery.io).

**Could I export my App and continue its development by usual programming way (I could hire a programmer for example) ?**

I mean I know a PAAS service covers a lot of things like

- Deployment on the Mobile targetted platform (App Store, Google Play)
- Versionning
- ...

So unlike Cross-platform Services (Appcelerator, PhoneGap which requires coding skills btw), I feel like adopting a PAAS is to be trapped on their service until the end of subscription.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Those PaaS services I tried are pretty restrictive for the most part. So you can sometimes download the code but its not something you can use since it relies on the cloud. The best way to judge if a PaaS is restrictive is too look at their pricing, if its "per app pricing" then you can expect a lot of restrictions when you try to leave.

I eventually settled on [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/). It might be a bit too code heavy for your sensibilities but I like it because of Java. Its open source so you can skip our PaaS services altogether and still use the API although admittedly I haven't tried that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately on Appery.io, it looks like the "per app pricing" is applied. I guess I'll try http://configure.it (I saw a good review on it about my needs). Otherwise I'll try https://www.codenameone.com/ as well once I learn programming a little bit.

Comment: I hadn't heard of configure.it they must be new. Either way looking at their site it seems like they bill per project also (I'm guessing project = app)